# Book series about a man who discovers advanced alien artifacts on the moon

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I am trying to recall the title of a book series I read in 1980-1981 where the hero was a human astronaut that discovered an alien aircraft crashed on the surface of the moon.  His investigation of the crash site gave him access to alien robots that empowered him to force peace on earth and led to his adventures throughout the universe - some of which involved time travel, etc.  It was a simple paperback novel series that was easy to read without a lot of heavy science.  Is anyone familiar with this series?

Comment: Isn't this can be somehow a [Space Odyssey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Odyssey) by Arthur Clarke? Looks very similar to the first two books.

Comment: "...alien aircraft on the Moon"?

Answer (score 9):

That sounds like the long-running [Perry Rhodan](http://www.perry-rhodan.us/faq/faq.html#faq3) series.

From the site:

> The main story line starts in 1971 - ten years into the future at the time of writing. Perry Rhodan and three other American astronauts are the first humans to land on the moon. Soon after their landing they discover a crashed space ship. It belongs to an alien race called Arkonides. Rhodan uses the vastly superior technology of the Arkonides to prevent World War Three and politically unite Earth as Terra. Within a few years the Terrans have built their first own faster than light space ships and push into space. The universe, it turns out, is packed with intelligent races. Many of them have mastered space travel thousands of years ago and established huge empires. On one of his first trips Rhodan encounters IT, an incredibly old and powerful immortal being. Granting the Terrans 20,000 years to embark upon their cosmic destiny and bring peace to the Milky Way galaxy, IT bestows Rhodan and his closest friends with immortality. This is the beginning of a future history unique to science fiction. It pictures the long journey of mankind to the stars - and into unknown dimensions.

[Perry Rhodan Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_Rhodan)

Comment: +1 Nice find - I hunted for this one without success.  Will be curious to see if Shaka validates as correct answer.  I added reference to the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Perry Rhodan! Of course! Thank you Greenstone Walker and Stan for the deep dig on this one. Sorry I did not respond sooner - new to this forum and did not realize that I had to verify my email address before I could access this answer. The moment I saw the name 'Perry Rhodan' I immediately remembered that that was the series I was reading - not the magazine media - but certainly one of the paperback versions. Sadly, I was hoping to purchase the complete set - fat chance at 2,600 installments of what appears to be a collectors' series. Oh well; I enjoyed what I was able to read. Your efforts we

Comment: @user13602 please follow [this guide](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) to have your two accounts merged. The rest of the comment reads:  *Your efforts were greatly appreciated. Shaka*